# How to manage layout for different device

Tags: android

Actually I want to know how can we manage the layout in android while doing our app. I build a calculator app for my `Nexus S` device. Now when I build the app in my device it doesn't match the screen resolution. Moreover when I maintain the layout for `Nexus S` device then it's ok for that but when I use another device then again the same problem arises. So is there any way by which I can maintain the app so that in every device it fits the screen automatically. Please suggest to me.

Regards
Anshuman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this ..
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It has been explained quite nicely here that how to create layout that to support multiple screens.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample example for that....so that i can know how that can be implemented

Comment: you should use RelativeLayout for your UI so that it will fit to all screens.

Comment: Am glad that it is working .You should accept the answer if it is helpful to you ? thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put layouts for different screens in specially named directories. You can find all details about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html